# Making the most of Glitterlance (Lulu Q)

Tags: league-of-legends

Glitterlance is a nice piercing spell that is fired by both Lulu and Pix, but a potential target can only be damaged by one. Problem is, most of the time Pix is close by and the two paths have a great degree of overlap (except when he is on enemies or allies using `Help, Pix!`)

I've tried to move laterally quickly during fights to reduce the overlap a little bit; but that is harder to do in big fights when there is more to keep track of.

How do I maximise the potential of Glitterlance attack to take full advantage of Pix' shot besides my own?

Edit: Both answers below are good, but as indicated I do know about `Help, Pix!` and am wondering on what *else* I can do besides that combo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're in a big team battle, chances are your `Glitterlance` will hit multiple targets as long as you fire into the mass of the enemy.  However, if you're looking for something more strategic besides aiming it into the majority, really `Help, Pix!` is the only real answer to spreading out the bolts.

If you cast `Help, Pix!` on an enemy, you can then almost assuredly hit them with `Glitterlance` even if they're running away, while still aiming your normal bolt at an enemy right in front of you.  An alternative to this (which I rarely, if ever, see used) is that you can actually cast `Help, Pix!` on a minion and launch the second bolt from *that* point (as long as the minion stays alive).  This can be incredibly useful for slowing down a fleeing enemy or just extending the range and effectiveness of your `Glitterlance`.

And finally, don't forget that `Help, Pix!` can also be cast on allies -- meaning you can then launch the Q from them, as well.  With this versatility, its use is actually very customizable, even if it requires a good bit of creativity and fast thinking.

Answer (score 1):

During team fights you usually want to use your Help Pix on your allied AD carry. Position yourself so the Glitterlance will hit as many of your opponents in a single shot.

When chasing multiple enemies you Help Pix the nearest opponent and the Glitterlance through them all.

When enemies are chasing a teammate, Help Pix -> Glitterlance can make wonders.

In laning phase when playing as a support I like to Help Pix the opponent's AD carry, then wait a moment and use Glitterlance for a guaranteed damage.

EDIT: When playing support Lulu, the damage fro Glitterlance is not usually what you are aiming for but the utility.